# I have 3 different email adress I want all the enteries of these by one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Like From column email_address , I have 100 emails address data( Some of the emails are repeated, Like abc@test.com has 4 enteries). My table name is Java_testing_Lp. I have 3 specific emails (abc@test.com, xyz@test.com and pqr@test.com), how could I fetch their data by one query of sql. I want to know fetch the rows which have enteries with these 3 emails.   Using MySQL workbench

Comment: Edit your table and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Like From column email_address , I have 100 emails address data( Some of the emails are repeated, Like abc@test.com has 4 enteries).  My table name is  Java_testing_Lp. I have 3 specific emails (abc@test.com, xyz@test.com and pqr@test.com), how could I fetch their data by one query of sql.

Comment: data base is mysql

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select distinct email_address from Java_testing_Lp 
where email_address in ('abc@test.com', 'xyz@test.com','pqr@test.com')
```